# Map load event to corresponding image src

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have an image, the `src` of which I am rapidly changing. I have a handler attached to the image element's `load` event. Is there a way to get the `src` corresponding to the `load` event being fired, without instantiating a new image object every time I load an image?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have something like this:

```
function eventHandler(event) {
  // event.currentTarget holds your element, query it to get info
}
```

as function bound to the event, if you use jQuery you could do something like

```
$(event.currentTarget).attr('src');
```

to get the current `src`.

Comment: Hi, sorry what I meant was getting the src of the image when the load event was fired. Since I'm always changing the src, the "current" src will be quite far ahead of the src I'm trying to get.

Answer (score 0):

First, it's easier to handle the event if it's in the handler's definition:

```
function image_load(event) {
    //...
}
```

Then, you will need to access the element that just fired the event, which is possible to obtain like this:

```
function image_load(event) {
    var src=event.target.src;
    //...
}
```

BUT, nothing is that simple.. you have to deal with cross-browser incompatibilies:

```
function image_load(event) {
    var evt=event||window.event; // data is either in event or window.event
    var img=evt.target||evt.srcElement; // eiter in .target or .srcElement
    var src=img.src; // :)
    //...
}
```

I assumed that you wanted a plain js solution as jQuery isn't tagged. In jQuery, incompatibilities are greatly reduced while dealing with the event chain, but it also reduces performances, it's up to you to use it or not.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's not possible to trigger a certain `onload` handler corresponding to the `src`, but you can store (all) previous `src`(s) to the image, and then choose a function to execute. Something like this:

```
window.onload = function () {   
    var n,
        images = document.images,
        imgOnload = function (e) {
            var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
            // do something with target.previousSrc
            target.previousSrc = target.src;
            // target.previousSrc.push(target.src);
            return;
        };
    for (n = 0; n < images.length; n++) {
        if (images[n].addEventListener) {
            images[n].addEventListener('load', imgOnload, false);
        } else {
            images[n].attachEvent('onload', imgOnload);
        }
        images[n].previousSrc = images[n].src;
        // images[n].previousSrc = [];
        // images[n].previousSrc.push(images[n].src);
    }
    return;
}
```

`document.images` here contains all the images in the document, but ofcourse you can create your own collection of the images you need.

A live demo at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TeekN/1/) (using only the latest `src`).